# What are the ways to restrict the User to click a button more than once in Windows c# application?

Tags: c#

What are the ways to restrict the User to click a button more than once in Windows c# application ? I dont want them to click more than once, which leads to a problem.

Can i change the make the cursor invisible after clicking once or any cother can be done ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the button on the click event. No more click events will be generated.

Answer (score 5):

1. (best option) Fix your code so there's no problem.
2. Disable the button when you get the first click event.